# list comprehension in place of nested loop avoiding item duplicity

Tags: python, list-comprehension, unique, nested-loops

I have some functions which retrive lists of items, matrix of itens.
after retrieving a matrix I need to put the itens in a new list, and avoid duplicated ones.
With nested for loops it´s easy, but I would like to know how to perform the same with list comprehension.
My problem is being to put the condition to avoid to insert the duplicated one:
something like this:

pseudocode:

```
new= [['Captain Marvel', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Deadpool 2'], ['Inhumans', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Venom', 'American Assassin', 'Black Panther']]

lista2 =[]
for movieL in new:
        lista2 = [val
                for sublist in new
                for val in sublist
              #if val not in lista2 this does not work
]
```

Result:

```
['Captain Marvel', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Deadpool 2', 'Inhumans', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Venom', 'American Assassin', 'Black Panther']
```

Comment: Why not just use `set`: `{val for sublist in new for val in sublist}`?

Comment: I didn´t know that. thanks, really easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sorting matters:

```
new = [['Captain Marvel', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Deadpool 2'], ['Inhumans', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Venom', 'American Assassin', 'Black Panther']]
lst = [item for sublist in new for item in sublist]
print(sorted(list(set(lst)), key=lambda x: lst.index(x)))
```

If it doesn't matter:

```
new = [['Captain Marvel', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Deadpool 2'], ['Inhumans', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Venom', 'American Assassin', 'Black Panther']]
print(list(set([item for sublist in new for item in sublist])))
```

Comment: the list new is dynamic, and sorting doesn´t matter at all. your 2nd approach fits perfectly. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If keeping the original order is not important in the result, you can take advantage of sets, and use a set union operation:

```
from functools import reduce


new= [['Captain Marvel', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Deadpool 2'], ['Inhumans', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Venom', 'American Assassin', 'Black Panther']]
result = [*reduce(set.union, map(set, new))]
print(result)
#Outputs ['Captain Marvel', 'Venom', 'Black Panther', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'American Assassin', 'Inhumans', 'Deadpool 2', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'The Fate Of The Furious']
```

Alternatively, if you strictly need to use a comprehension syntax (in this case generator comprehension), you could use:

```
result = [*set(item for list_ in new for item in list_)]
```

Comment: I did not mention, but the list new is created dynamically, so it can keep more records... so, the list(set( (item for list_ in new for item in list_)) casting is the best option. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` to flatten all of your lists into a single one, and apply the `set()` to remove duplicates.

```
from itertools import chain
new= [['Captain Marvel', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Deadpool 2'], ['Inhumans', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Venom', 'American Assassin', 'Black Panther']]
set(chain.from_iterable(new))


{'Captain Marvel', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Inhumans', 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'Black Panther', 'Deadpool 2', 'Venom', 'American Assassin'}
```